# Is it possible to apply more than one poison to a single weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, poison

Title says it all. Can I apply two different poison-types to a single weapon or arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's possibly legal but also possibly not a lot of fun

Like this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105140/8610), so far I've found nothing specifically *prohibiting* the application of multiple doses of the same or different poisons to a single weapon or unit of ammunition.

However, this DM would *not* allow such a practice.

That's because [it's trivial for NPCs and some PCs to acquire large amounts of poison](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#minor-creation-psionic), and, if a weapon *can* have multiple doses of poison applied to it, determining *why* folks *don't* coat their weapons in, like, 20 doses of [drow poison](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#drow-poison) (*DMG* 297) (75 gp; 0 lbs.) *all the time* becomes an exercise that's likely to strain the setting's verisimilitude. Seriously, many threats can be temporarily neutralized by—or eliminated outright by ability damage from—*one* failed saving throw against the right poison, and forcing an arbitrarily high number of saving throws against the right poison all but guarantees at least one failed saving throw.

Many players already resent the game's reliance on save-or-die effects, and a weapon coated in *enough* doses of poison becomes a *save-and-die-anyway* effect… at least, until combatants are immune to poison, which every PC and NPC in such a setting will be obligated to become. (Note that for combat purposes this can happen as early as level 3 when the 2nd-level Clr spell [*delay poison*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#delay-poison) [conj] (*PH* 217) comes online, although PCs still must deal with the poisons in their systems when that spell's duration finally expires.)

This DM would rather not engage in the arms race that would ensue were he to rule that it's acceptable to apply multiple doses of poison to the same weapon. One possible save-or-die or save-or-suck poison effect per weapon attack is sufficient.

Comment: I think this answer is slightly off the mark - you answer "why not 20 doses of the same poison?" but the question asks "why not 20 different poisons?"

Comment: @fectin And also the question's title. I'm honestly not sure what difference it makes. Would it be more difficult if the DM ruled all the poisons must be different? That's just more Dumpster-diving. I mean, apparently, one can do *both* different *and* identical poisons. The key, however, isn't *Can I apply multiple doses of different poisons to this weapon?* but *Should the DM allow multiple doses of different poisons to be applied to any weapon?*

Comment: I read your comment as "it's a distinction without a difference," which seems very reasonable. However, that still means you're answering a question distinct from the one asked. Also, I particularly notice the you talk about forcing saves against the "right" poison, which suggests that all the other poisons are wrong (so if the limit is one-each, you'd still only be forcing one save against the "right" poison). I like your answer; I just think it's a short move from okay to great.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

I can find nothing that says otherwise. Your GM is of course, the final arbiter of such things and he may house rule it.